# Not able to step into .NET Framework Source Code after upgrading to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, debug-symbols

After upgrading to Visual Studio 2015, I'm not able to step into the code of several of the .NET Framework assemblies anymore.

Everything was setup as per the instructions at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/setup.html

I'm able to step into some assemblies such as System.Xml.dll and System.Xml.Linq.dll, but I'm not able to step into others such as mscorlib.dll.

To try to figure out what's happening, I created a few test projects using different versions (4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6) of the .NET Framework without success.

For instance. Given the following code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication_451
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new string('a', 50));
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

implemented in three different console projects - one for each version of the .NET Framework, I'm not able to step into String nor Console and when I peek into the Symbol Load Information for mscorlib, I get:

**.NET 4.5.1**

```
C:\Users\alfred.myers\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication46\ConsoleApplication46\bin\Debug\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\symbols\dll\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\dll\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\bad2b04f3cb34c248fbd3f1e9dcf60202\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\SymbolCache\MicrosoftPublicSymbols\mscorlib.pdb\bad2b04f3cb34c248fbd3f1e9dcf60202\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
SYMSRV:  C:\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\BAD2B04F3CB34C248FBD3F1E9DCF60202\mscorlib.pdb - file not found


*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND


*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND


*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND


*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND


SYMSRV:  C:\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\BAD2B04F3CB34C248FBD3F1E9DCF60202\mscorlib.pdb not found


SYMSRV:  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols/mscorlib.pdb/BAD2B04F3CB34C248FBD3F1E9DCF60202/mscorlib.pdb not found


http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols: Symbols not found on symbol server.
SYMSRV:  C:\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\BAD2B04F3CB34C248FBD3F1E9DCF60202\mscorlib.pdb - file not found


*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND


*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND


INFO:  HTTP_STATUS_OK


SYMSRV:  C:\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\BAD2B04F3CB34C248FBD3F1E9DCF60202\mscorlib.pdb - file not found


SYMSRV:  mscorlib.pdb from https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: 121231 bytes 

https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: Symbols downloaded from symbol server.
C:\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\BAD2B04F3CB34C248FBD3F1E9DCF60202\mscorlib.pdb: Symbols loaded.
```

**.NET 4.5.2**

```
C:\Users\alfred.myers\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication452\ConsoleApplication452\bin\Debug\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\symbols\dll\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\dll\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\bad2b04f3cb34c248fbd3f1e9dcf60202\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\SymbolCache\MicrosoftPublicSymbols\mscorlib.pdb\bad2b04f3cb34c248fbd3f1e9dcf60202\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
SYMSRV:  C:\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\BAD2B04F3CB34C248FBD3F1E9DCF60202\mscorlib.pdb - file not found


*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND


*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND


*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND


*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND


SYMSRV:  C:\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\BAD2B04F3CB34C248FBD3F1E9DCF60202\mscorlib.pdb not found


SYMSRV:  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols/mscorlib.pdb/BAD2B04F3CB34C248FBD3F1E9DCF60202/mscorlib.pdb not found


http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols: Symbols not found on symbol server.
SYMSRV:  C:\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\BAD2B04F3CB34C248FBD3F1E9DCF60202\mscorlib.pdb - file not found


*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND


*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND


INFO:  HTTP_STATUS_OK


SYMSRV:  C:\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\BAD2B04F3CB34C248FBD3F1E9DCF60202\mscorlib.pdb - file not found


SYMSRV:  mscorlib.pdb from https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: 121231 bytes 

https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: Symbols downloaded from symbol server.
C:\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\BAD2B04F3CB34C248FBD3F1E9DCF60202\mscorlib.pdb: Symbols loaded.
```

**.NET 4.6**

```
C:\Users\alfred.myers\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication46\ConsoleApplication46\bin\Debug\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\symbols\dll\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\dll\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\bad2b04f3cb34c248fbd3f1e9dcf60202\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\SymbolCache\MicrosoftPublicSymbols\mscorlib.pdb\bad2b04f3cb34c248fbd3f1e9dcf60202\mscorlib.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
SYMSRV:  C:\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\BAD2B04F3CB34C248FBD3F1E9DCF60202\mscorlib.pdb - file not found


*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND


*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND


*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND


*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND


SYMSRV:  C:\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\BAD2B04F3CB34C248FBD3F1E9DCF60202\mscorlib.pdb not found


SYMSRV:  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols/mscorlib.pdb/BAD2B04F3CB34C248FBD3F1E9DCF60202/mscorlib.pdb not found


http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols: Symbols not found on symbol server.
SYMSRV:  C:\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\BAD2B04F3CB34C248FBD3F1E9DCF60202\mscorlib.pdb - file not found


*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND


*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND


INFO:  HTTP_STATUS_OK


SYMSRV:  C:\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\BAD2B04F3CB34C248FBD3F1E9DCF60202\mscorlib.pdb - file not found


SYMSRV:  mscorlib.pdb from https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: 121231 bytes 

https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: Symbols downloaded from symbol server.
C:\SymbolCache\mscorlib.pdb\BAD2B04F3CB34C248FBD3F1E9DCF60202\mscorlib.pdb: Symbols loaded.
```

I sent an e-mail to the folks referred to at the Setup Page a few days ago, but nobody replied.

**Any clues on how to troubleshoot this issue?**

Comment: Your tests with 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 are not useful, you have only one version of mscorlib.dll on your machine.  Microsoft is not very good at keeping the reference source symbol server updated when they release updates for security problems and critical bugs.  Like [the one that was deployed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/08/11/august-2015-net-security-updates.aspx) in early August, the one with the BAD2B04F3CB34C248FBD3F1E9DCF60202 hash you have now.  Nothing you can do about it but wait.

Comment: As a workaround you could install JetBrains dotPeek and turn on its symbol server feature. It will generate sources from the binaries (not the same thing as the actual sources) and will allow you to step through them. https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/dotPeek+Symbol+Server+and+PDB+Generation

Comment: @HansPassant I suppose they're actually quite good at publishing their sources, but the process of reviews, approvals etc before source is shown is extensive. I'm glad they don't wait to release their hotfix until all the paperwork is processed stamped and done with.

Comment: Hmm, not really, it is just a networking deficiency.  The msdl.microsoft.com server is wired up to the build server just fine and automatically gets the updates, the referencesource.microsoft.com server appears to be updated by sneakerware.